# PseudoInverse of a variable matrix is very slow

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I was trying to `PseudoInverse` a matrix of 4x4 size with variables as below and it took about 10 minutes and no results yet. Then I lost the patience and aborted it. 
I am wondering if it is a general case that `PseudoInverse` function of a variable matrix is very slow or is there any problem with the matrix?

Can someone give some insight into this?

```
Y = MatrixForm[{{gm1 + 1/RG + 1/ro1 + 1/Z1, -(1/Z1), -gm1 - 1/RG, -(1/ro1)}, 
 {-(1/Z1), gm2 + 1/RG + 1/ro2 + 1/Z1, -(1/ro2), -gm2 - 1/RG}, {-(1/RG), -gm2 - 1/ro2, 1/RG + 1/ro2, 
  gm2}, {-gm1 - 1/ro1, -(1/RG), gm1, 1/RG + 1/ro1}}]; 
Z = PseudoInverse[Y];
```

**UPDATE**:

I ran it again and it finished after a long time with an output saying large output. Is there any way to speed up the calculation?

Also I found the discussion from the link and checked the function  Gianluca Gorni wrote. It gave result almost immediately!

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/F4lF5hevli4

Comment: try without  `MatrixForm` as that is a wrapper. But why you are using `PseudoInverse` on symbolic matrix? Also, it is singular. Try `Inverse` and see.

Comment: I have just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Still running and maybe 10 minutes or more...

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed to be a bug.

Comment: @Nasser: I know that it is singular already. `PseudoInverse ` also works on singular matrix and I want to use that for some calculation.

Comment: It might be because the size blow up for such large terms. May be if you wait more it will finish.

Comment: @Nasser: it finished now and saying that "large output". Is there any way to speed up the calculation?

Comment: good it finished. as I said, it was due to large size. to reduce the size, you could try simplify with complexExpand as well, if all your variables are real.

Comment: All variables are real but I didn't specify them whether real or imaginary. I just try to use ComplexExpand for the matrix but the output is exactly same as input,

Comment: @Nasser: I've just updated the post again and included the link to Gianluca Gorni's function. I checked his function and it gave the result almost immediately. Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this so that people have an idea of what they're up against.

First, let us temporarily replace the reciprocals with different symbols, to temporarily mitigate expression swell:

```
mn = {{gm1 + 1/RG + 1/ro1 + 1/Z1, -1/Z1, -gm1 - 1/RG, -1/ro1},
      {-1/Z1, gm2 + 1/RG + 1/ro2 + 1/Z1, -1/ro2, -gm2 - 1/RG},
      {-1/RG, -gm2 - 1/ro2, 1/RG + 1/ro2, gm2},
      {-gm1 - 1/ro1, -1/RG, gm1, 1/RG + 1/ro1}} /.
     {RG -> 1/rgi, Z1 -> 1/zi, ro1 -> 1/ri1, ro2 -> 1/ri2} // Simplify
```

When computing a complicated matrix expression, it helps to apply an appropriate decomposition to it. Let's use `LUDecomposition[]`:

```
{lu, piv, cond} = LUDecomposition[mn] // FullSimplify;
```

Note the `LUDecomposition::sing` warning; this is fine, since the proper factorization is computed anyway:

```
perm = IdentityMatrix[4][[piv]];
lf = LowerTriangularize[lu, -1] + IdentityMatrix[4];
uf = UpperTriangularize[lu];

perm.mn == lf.uf // Simplify
   True
```

Note that things are arranged so that `uf` is the singular factor.

Conceptually, we can compute the pseudoinverse as

```
LeastSquares[uf, LinearSolve[lf, perm]]
```

and the `LinearSolve[lf, perm]` part is simple enough:

```
tmp = Simplify[LinearSolve[lf, perm]];
```

The problematic part is in computing the Moore-Penrose inverse of `uf`; structurally, it is similar to the following matrix:

```
cm = ReplacePart[UpperTriangularize[Array[C, {4, 4}]], {4, 4} -> 0]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \mathtt{C[1,1]} & \mathtt{C[1,2]} & \mathtt{C[1,3]} & \mathtt{C[1,4]} \\
 0 & \mathtt{C[2,2]} & \mathtt{C[2,3]} & \mathtt{C[2,4]} \\
 0 & 0 & \mathtt{C[3,3]} & \mathtt{C[3,4]} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

which has a very complicated pseudoinverse (even after removing all the instances of `Conjugate`):

```
LeafCount[pinv = Simplify[PseudoInverse[cm] /. Conjugate -> Identity]]
   1968
```

Then,

```
uinv = Simplify[pinv /.
                DeleteCases[Thread[Flatten[cm] -> Flatten[uf]], HoldPattern[0 -> 0]]];
```

and finally

```
res = FullSimplify[uinv.tmp /. {rgi -> 1/RG, zi -> 1/Z1, ri1 -> 1/ro1, ri2 -> 1/ro2}]
```

Comment: So does this mean Mathematica's PseudoInverse is not good? Did you see my update with the link to  Gianluca Gorni 's function? I tried and it gave the result almost immediately.

Comment: I hadn't tried it yet, but looking at the code, his route seems to be more straightforward than mine. I would say that the problem with `PseudoInverse[]` is that it is trying to be too general (recall that *Mathematica* assumes everything is complex unless told otherwise).

Comment: I would like to check how fast it is if all variables are real. How to add that assumption for the checking?

Comment: I don't really know; it doesn't seem like there's an appropriate option setting in `PseudoInverse[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`PseudoInverse` has no option for assuming variables are real. This is a rare (I think) case where one can simply cheat using `Assuming`

```
mn = {{gm1 + 1/RG + 1/ro1 + 1/Z1, -1/Z1, -gm1 - 1/RG, -1/ro1}, {-1/Z1,
     gm2 + 1/RG + 1/ro2 + 1/Z1, -1/ro2, -gm2 - 1/RG}, {-1/RG, -gm2 - 
     1/ro2, 1/RG + 1/ro2, gm2}, {-gm1 - 1/ro1, -1/RG, gm1, 
    1/RG + 1/ro1}};
mvars = Variables[mn];

AbsoluteTiming[
 Assuming[Element[mvars, Reals], psi = PseudoInverse[mn];]]

(* Out[1711]= {9.957832, Null} *)

LeafCount[psi]

(* Out[1712]= 471786 *)
```

I would not claim this is good behavior, on the part of the code or the developer. It works because the internal code has some hooks to use `Refine`, and that catches the outer assumptions.

Some day we should make this a bona fide option.

Comment: Wow, I learned to use Variables and Element to take all variables from the matrix and then assume they are reals. This method is so fast!